# What is uri segment in codeigniter for specific condition?

Tags: codeigniter

My url is `http://example.come/search?s=code/100`
I am using codeigniter for my application.

```
echo $this->uri->segment(1);  Result is 'search';
```

but what is `uri segment` for `100`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you've created the url is incorrect. The query string should be at the end... ie. `http://example.come/search/100?s=code`. Then the following should work:

```
echo $this->uri->segment(2);
```